# Opening the audio menu (systray) in Unity when playing in Rhythmbox uses 100% processor

Tags: unity, rhythmbox

If I just click on the speaker icon on the top right corner in unity, processor usage rockets to 100% until I close the menu.
I am playing some music on Rhythm-box and have conky.

Is it doing something without a sleep() or something? Does it have a do-nothing loop?

The funniest thing is that ubuntu-bug unity sent me to report a bug *ḧere* in askubuntu.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [How to report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Regards,